# Is there any new game+ exclusive content in Trails of Cold Steel 3?

Tags: trails-of-cold-steel-3

In Trails of Cold Steel 2 there was the book series called the black records that could only be collected in NG+.

Is there something similar, some quests, etc. in Trails of Cold Steel 3 that are only available in NG+?